# auto scaling in monogame for windows store games using xna and xaml

Tags: monogame

Is there any best way to do auto scaling for windows store games developed in monogame,I am facing many problems ,Currently i am doing this.
following is two lines of code which is useful for keeping my games windows to fixed scale.

```
 graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 768;
  graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1024;
```

but this is solving my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see bleow code for autoscaling for your store game
two vars scalesx and scaley , divide the current deveice width and height by your required resolution i am taking 1024 and 768 because in pc's this smallest resolution those which will run windows 8 OS.
when you pass x and y co-ordinates for rectangles and vectors multiply it scalex and scaley and the pos according to 1024*768 resolution

i have taken x of rect  (int)(scalex*102)  ------>by this, x of rect is at 102px but for autoscale multiply it by scalex.

```
  ` public static float scaley,scalex;
        scalex = (float)graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 1024;
        scaley = (float)graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height / 768;

   jumposition = new Rectangle((int)(scalex*102),(int)(scaley*320),(int)(scalex*250),(int)(scaley* 250));`
```